# How can I resolved Client requires user consent in keycloak?

Tags: node.js, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I need to add user consent in keycloak user when user is created. I am using API

http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/users

and Turn on and try to create the users but I am getting error like:

> Client requires user consent

I don't know which parameter I need to pass to fix this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What is Consent ?**

> Consent is when you as an admin want a user to give permission to a
> client before that client can participate in the authentication
> process. After a user provides their credentials, Keycloak will pop up
> a screen identifying the client requesting a login and what identity
> information is requested of the user. User can decide whether or not
> to grant the request.

So what the process of creating user via api or curl command

1. Generate the token with the help of userid/password/client/realm information
2. Now pass this token to the create user restapi or curl command with date[username/emailid...] etc

So in your case you are getting the issue about

```
Client requires user consent
```

So it mean in your client(Which used to generate the token),`Consent Required` option is `true` in place of false.
OR
You are using wrong client to create the user.

[image]

FYI :- Generally we have two different clients for back-end and fronted application with some major differences.